# How to find out which symbol is used as a decimal / list separator?

Tags: r, windows, decimal-point

I want to export a table using `write.csv`. There are 2 flavors of `write.csv` changing the defaults for the field and the decimal separator.

- `write.csv` uses `.` as the decimal point separator and `,` as the field separator
- `write.csv2` uses `,` as the decimal point separator and `;` as the field separator

I want, however, to use the local regional setting (which may be altered from the `locale` by the user):

[image: Region Settings]

Thus, for this user I would like to use `.` as a decimal separator and `;` as a field separator. How could I query these settings from `R`?

Comment: `Sys.localeconv()` gets information on the decimal point separator and some other bits, but doesn't give you the list separator

Comment: Thanks, halfway through - I saw that you deleted your answer undelete it and I will gladly accept it unless there is also an answer with the filed separator.

Comment: I think it has a problem, because the decimal separator '.' is default with R, and `Sys.localeconv()` only looks at R, not the system. The documentation says "Normally R is run without looking at the value of LC_NUMERIC, so the decimal point remains '.'. So the first three of these components will only be useful if you have set the locale category LC_NUMERIC using Sys.setlocale in the current R session (when R may not work correctly)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the corresponding registry entries following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-query

For example:

```r
# get list separator
system('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Control Panel\\International" /v sList', intern = TRUE)

# get decimal symbol
system('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Control Panel\\International" /v sDecimal', intern = TRUE)
```

Sorry, I'm not familiar with Window's built-in command line `cmd` & I can't find out how to only extract the value itself. However, this can easily be done in R...

Works on my Windows 10 virtual machine...